# Altering the Y-axis positioning of an SVG polygon with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, yaxis

I'm writing a lo-fi SGV choose your own adventure to post on a forum. I am attempting to animate the road markings to simulate forward travel, but I can't work out how to manipulate the Y axis via JavaScript. At the moment I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- Decide if you trust the driver. If you do, comment yes, if not, comment no. This will change the way the story progresses... -->
    <head>
        <title>Lost on an Alien Planet. Episode One: A New Moon. </title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <svg width="550" height="550">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="550" height="220" fill="black" />
        <circle id="moon" cx="175" cy="120" r="100" stroke="#ee1015" stroke-width="2" fill="#ff1519" />
        <circle id="top_asteroid" cx="290" cy="50" r="17" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="#313131" />
        <circle cx="220" cy="110" r="20" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="#131313" />
        <circle cx="20" cy="200" r="15" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="#242525" />

        <rect x="0" y="219" width="550" height="282" fill="blue" />
        <polygon points="100,500 180,220 346,220 426,500"
        style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,220 265,220 265,240 250,240"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,250 265,250 265,270 250,270"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,280 265,280 265,300 250,300"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,310 265,310 265,330 250,330"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,340 265,340 265,360 250,360"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,370 265,370 265,390 250,390"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,400 265,400 265,420 250,420"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,430 265,430 265,450 250,450"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
        <polygon class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" points="250,460 265,460 265,480 250,480"
        style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
      </svg>

      <script>
          setInterval(function(){
              var marking = document.getElementById("base_roadmarking");
              var pos = 0;
              frame_first = true;
              elem_pos = 0;

              if(frame_first) {
                  elem_pos = marking.style.top;
                  pos += 10;
                  elem_pos = pos + 'px';
              }
              else {
                  elem_pos = marking.style.top;
                  pos -= 10;
                  elem_pos = pos + 'px';
              }

          }, 500);
      </script>

      <p>You wake from a dark dream to find yourself on an alien planet. Ahead is a red moon orbited by asteroids that seem to move with a disconcerting quickness. Your vehicle drives slowly toward the horizon. All around you are the sounds of strange wolf-like creatures howling. You are sitting in the passenger seat, unsure where your driver is taking you. But you trust him... at least, you think you trust him...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it's not working. I would like a very simple solution using raw JavaScript if possible (e.g. no code libraries and no HTML `<animate>` element). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript won't take multiple IDs, use getElementsByClassName instead :

Also please use rect instead of poly (personal pref), and try the code i showed
press on button "try it" for animation

```js
function run() {
 setInterval(function(){
 var marking = document.getElementsByClassName("roadmarking");
 var i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < marking.length; i++) {
  frame_first = marking[i].y.baseVal.value; 
  var show= document.getElementById("show");
  //show.innerHTML = marking[i].y.baseVal.value;
  if(frame_first<500) {
   marking[i].y.baseVal.value += 10;
   }
  else {
   marking[i].y.baseVal.value -= 290;
  }
 }
},500);}
```

```html
<html>
<!-- Decide if you trust the driver. If you do, comment yes, if not, comment no. This will change the way the story progresses... -->
<head>
    <title>Lost on an Alien Planet. Episode One: A New Moon. </title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="550" height="550">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="550" height="220" fill="black" />
    <circle id="moon" cx="175" cy="120" r="100" stroke="#ee1015" stroke-width="2" fill="#ff1519" />
    <circle id="top_asteroid" cx="290" cy="50" r="17" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="#313131" />
    <circle cx="220" cy="110" r="20" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="#131313" />
    <circle cx="20" cy="200" r="15" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="#242525" />

    <rect x="0" y="219" width="550" height="282" fill="blue" />
    <polygon points="100,500 180,220 346,220 426,500"
    style="fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="490" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="220" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="250" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="280" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="310" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="340" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="370" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="400" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="430" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
    <rect class="roadmarking" id="base_roadmarking" x="250" y="460" width="15" height="20"
    style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:2" />
  </svg>

  <script>
    
  </script>
  <p id="show">You wake from a dark dream to find yourself on an alien planet. Ahead is a red moon orbited by asteroids that seem to move with a disconcerting quickness. Your vehicle drives slowly toward the horizon. All around you are the sounds of strange wolf-like creatures howling. You are sitting in the passenger seat, unsure where your driver is taking you. But you trust him... at least, you think you trust him...</p>
<br><button onclick="run()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great! Not sure if the road-markings should be disappearing off the road though...

Comment: I just made an edit so that they will go back on top after doing so, just calibrate according to your needs

Comment: There's now an odd glitch with one of the markings being a different distance from the others, and also it doesn't quite simulate movement. But either way I didn't want to steal the code, just to learn, so this should be enough. If you fix these things I'll accept your answer straight away, if not I'll wait for other answers and accept if this is the best one after a day :).